# .padStart() returns the wrong count when using emojis

Tags: javascript, emoji

I'm trying to output 20 emojis, so I figured a simple way to do this would be to use the [`String.padStart()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart). However, I'm only getting half the expected amount. Consider the example below with a pumpkin:

```js
const emoji = "".padStart(20, "");
const symbol = "".padStart(20, "$");

// Outputs 10 emojis
console.log(emoji);

// Outputs 20 $ symbols
console.log(symbol);
```

I know there are lots of workarounds to this issue, but why am I getting different counts between emojis and regular keyboard symbols when using `.padStart()`?

Comment: Probably because emojis are multi byte.

Comment: Javascript uses UTF16, and all length checks are on UTF16-codeunits, meaning emoji count as length two.

Comment: PS: as a general thing, "visible as one symbol" can have a lot of different representations in data. It gets even more difficult for grapheme clusters, e.g. "️‍", which has a length of `6` (not only are most parts outside of the basic multilingual plane, it's using a concept in unicode of combining multiple characters via zero-width-joiners and variation-selectors. Unicode is a mess in some aspects.

Comment: `"".length` gives 2

Comment: Why won't you use `.repeat`?

Comment: @ASDFGerte Thank you for explaining the underlying behavior in your comment. That's what I was looking for. If you'd like to post it as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution that answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

Emojis use internally more than one character, so they don't work well with `.padStart`

Use `.repeat` instead

```js
console.log(''.repeat(20))
```