# Why is it that emojis require two padding spaces to render correctly?

Tags: javascript

When i put an odd number of padding to the string, and i use emoji as the padding itself, the last emoji looks broken. I just started learning JS. thanks for help. As for the code itself i tried:

```js
console.log(''.padEnd(5,''));
```

Comment: emojis can have variable widths, and when you're using them for padding, it can cause unexpected visual results

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72874903/padstart-returns-the-wrong-count-when-using-emojis

Comment: Hint: `''.length` is 2, not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some emoji are sequence of multiple characters. The characters alone do not have a meaning but when they are put together, their combination produces a new symbol.

You can check the [`.length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) of a string to find out its length in characters.

[`String.prototype.padEnd()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd) appends its second argument repeatedly to the input string until it reaches the target length. The last occurrence of the padding string is usually truncated (when the length of the needed padding is not multiple of the length of the padding string).
Check the outcome of `''.padEnd(5, 'abc')`.

```js
console.log(''.padEnd(5, 'abc'));
```

Because the length of `''` is 2 and you want a padding of 5 characters, the request is fulfilled by using 2 and a half instances of `''`. Half of `''` is not a meaningful character and, if it is not present in the font that you are using in console, it is represented using the [Unicode replacement character (`'�'`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)).

```js
console.log(''.length);
```

Because you pad the empty string, I guess that what you actually want is to get a string of 5 `''` emoji characters. This is easier to accomplish using [`String.prototype.repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) and you don't have to worry about multiple-char sequences. Of course, the length of the generated string is 10, not 5.

```js
console.log(''.repeat(5));
```

Comment: "*Each of these characters has its own meaning alone*" - not really, [isolated surrogate code points have no general interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates).

Comment: `.padEnd(5 * ''.length, '')` doesn't actually work for arbitrary strings either.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you. I removed the incorrect statements.